# Refresh JTable when setAutoCreateRowSorter is true

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have written a default table render as follows:

```
public class CustTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        try {

            Object cellObj = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 7); 
            double cellValue = (Double) cellObj;

            if (cellValue < 0) {
                comp.setBackground(new Color(255, 48, 48));
            } else if (cellValue == 0) {
                comp.setBackground(new Color(173, 255, 47));
            } else {
                comp.setBackground(Color.white);
            }

            if (isSelected) {
                comp.setBackground(new Color(71, 60, 139));
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return comp;
    }
}
```

To highlight the rows which contain minus values of column 7, I have also set `setAutoCreateRowSorter` to `true`. My problem is when I click a header to sort according to it table is sorted but the highlighted row is not changed, therefore a wrong row is highlighted.

How to redraw the table when it is sorted?

Comment: Attach a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterListener.html to the table, and in the delegate method, call the doLayout of the table.

Comment: @govi - NO, a manual doLayout is _never_ needed. If that seems to solve a problem, there's something really wrong elsewhere

Comment: @kleopatra - hmm. yeah well, that's quite true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the coordinates passed into the renderer are in view coordinate system, you have to convert them to model coordinates before accessing the model:

```
  int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
  int modelColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
  cellObject = table.getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, modelColumn);
```